# Json transformation and validation using play 2

Tags: json, validation, scala, playframework

I am new to Play2. I would like to use it to validate and transform incoming json objects. Here is the code I have so far. I would like to know what is the recommended way for using transformers to validate and transform user input. I am also not sure the email2 function i defined (to handle JsString) is actually necessary or if there is a way to avoid defining it.

```
def email2(implicit reads:Reads[JsString]) : Reads[JsString] = 
pattern( """\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\b""".r, "validate.error.email" )

def pattern(regex: => scala.util.matching.Regex, error: String = "error.pattern")(implicit reads:Reads[JsString]) =
Reads[JsString]( js => reads.reads(js).flatMap { o =>
  regex.unapplySeq(o.value).map( _ => JsSuccess(o) ).getOrElse(JsError(error))
})

val transformer = (
  (__ \ '_id).json.put(JsString(new ObjectId().toString)) and
  (__ \ 'email).json.update(__.readNullable[JsString](email2)).orElse(JsNull))
  ) reduce

request.body.transform(transformer) match {
  case JsSuccess(value:JsValue,_)=>  Async {
        collection.insert(value).map{
          case someError:LastError if someError.err.isDefined =>  Ok(Json.obj("errors"->List("Insertion failed:"+Json.prettyPrint(value))))
          case others => Ok(value)
        }
      }
  case errors:JsError => Ok(Json.obj("errors"->JsError.toFlatJson(errors)))
```

In here I want to have email as an optional field, if the field exists, it should be valid email address, if the field doesn't exist I want null to be used. If email invalid, I want error message sent to user.

This code doesn't compile yet and I am not sure if they way I am using transformers and validating user input is really the right way.